# How can I delete an answer which I posted in error, which has already been deleted by a reviewer?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I was fiddling trying to get uMatrix working and accidentally posted what should have been a comment to another answer, but was actually posted as an answer.  It was noticed by a reviewer and deleted as a "low quality" answer (which it certainly was).  Now I want to permanently delete it, but can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: I'm confused about what kind of deletion you're after. Deleted is deleted. What would this next-level deletion look like?

Comment: @JeffSchaller It wouldn't even show up to me, when I looked at the question.  That is, it would really be deleted, not just "disabled for other users except for users with > 10,000 reputation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is already permanently deleted. You can just still see it because you are the post's owner, but other users cannot see it. "Deleted" content on these sites isn't really deleted, it is simply not shown to users unless they have at least 10,000 reputation or, as in this case, if they are the post's author.

So don't worry about it, it is deleted, it isn't bothering anyone and there's nothing wrong with leaving it.

Comment: I believed that if *I* deleted it, it would really be gone (even I wouldn't see it).  I can still see it in the current state that it's in, even if other users can't.  But I've never deleted an answer before, so that's just a guess.  If it's already in the most deleted state it can be in, then I guess there's nothing more I can do.